# Expectation of parameter: how to suggest test in this case?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

The given information are that $X_i(i=1, 2, … ,n)$ are following distribution with mean $E(X_i)=\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Null hypothesis is given as $H_0:\lim \frac{1}{n}\sum\mu_i =0$, and alternative hypothesis is $H_1:\lim\frac{1}{n} \sum\mu_i \neq 0$.

I need to suggest a test in this case. I know $\lim \frac{1}{n}\sum\mu_i =E(\mu_i)$ by WLLN. But is it possible to suggest a test in this case? I don't understand why the parameter can be included in the null hypothesis.

Comment: I've never seen hypothesis tests involving limits. What exactly is your null hypothesis? Is it$H_0: \mu = 0$ against $H_1: \mu \neq 0$? Or is the limit part of the null hypothesis?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Eli sorry.. I edited the hypothesis. The null hypothesis is $H_o: \lim \frac{1}{n} \sum \mu_i = 0$.

Comment: This null hypothesis is not testable, because it tells us *absolutely  nothing* about the distribution of any finite sample.

Comment: @whuber I can’t understand this problem, but this problem was given by my professor of statistics course. I just solved this setting $H_0 : \mu_i = 0$.